# Astar RPC endpoint returns error between block 1558933 to block 1848933

Tags: parachain, astar

I am trying to query the historical data (tx, ownership, etc.) of Cosmize Ticket NFT on Astar EVM. I got the error message when querying between `block 1558933` to `block 1848933`.

Below is how to reproduce the error:

1. request the `supportsInterface` function of the Cosmize Ticket pass contract (0x66B2E7e61681382cec6c609a4D6E06373DAAB42f) at the latest block, everything works fine.
   [image]
2. request the `supportsInterface` function of the Cosmize Ticket pass contract (0x66B2E7e61681382cec6c609a4D6E06373DAAB42f) at block 1558933, the RPC responds with the following error:
   `execution fatal: Module(ModuleError { index: 60, error: [7, 0, 0, 0], message: None })  (picture 2)`
   [image]

I am using https://evm.astar.network/ as the RPC endpoint since it is the only one supporting archive node. Please feel free to use the following request params to reproduce the error:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_call",
    "params": [
        {
            "from": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "data": "0x01ffc9a701ffc9a700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "to": "0x66B2E7e61681382cec6c609a4D6E06373DAAB42f"
        },
        "1558933"
    ],
    "id": 0
}
```

So far, based on my tests, I assume the rpc endpoint's block state storage has some internal error between `block 1558933` to `block 1848933`. Could anyone support on this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for report, it looks like this range of blocks has different EVM runtime API version that mismatch current client. We will investigate how to make it work in next release.

As workaround, would you try different node version locally, I suggest to use https://github.com/AstarNetwork/Astar/releases/tag/v4.15.0

Feel free to ask any questions.